# why is this optional method argument shared across different python objects?

Tags: python, oop, list, optional-arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

can anyone explain me this?

```
class Strange(object):
    def mutate(self, x=[]):
        x.append(1)
        return x

obj = Strange()
print obj.mutate()
another_obj = Strange()
print another_obj.mutate() 

>> [1]
>> [1, 1]
```

mutate() is called without the optional parameter. shouldn't x then always be []? what confuses me also is that the value of x is also shared across different objects...

Comment: [Python tag has a wonderful FAQ section](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/faq)

Comment: Interesting, but still a duplicate. SilentGhost is right.

Comment: +1 good Q. I see it's been well-answered before, but I would guess it's not easy to know how to search for that answer.

Comment: ok, thanks to this it's now clear for me: http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm